# Rating like Like/Dislike

Tags: modules

Hello!

I need a rating like Like/Dislike. That it would be possible to assign likes and sort posts by them. Are there any ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The Craft [Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com) is where you'd go to look for existing plugins/solutions for this.

The two I'm aware of that are related are:

https://plugins.craftcms.com/star-ratings

https://plugins.craftcms.com/upvote

Otherwise, you'd probably be looking at some custom plugin development.